# android push notification in phone gap not getting notifications

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

Hi I follow the steps below

1) I created the cordova project structure.
2) I added the platform( android).
3) I added the cordova plugin

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin.git#2.4.0
```

4) Bulid the cordova project.
5) Next I import the created app in android eclipse(4.4.2)
6) I wrote the code below in `index.js` file

```
 init: function(){
     alert("init");
    var pushNotification = window.plugins.pushNotification;

    pushNotification.register(successHandler, errorHandler, 
        {
            'senderID':'XXXXXXXXXX',
            'ecb':'onNotificationGCM' // callback function
        }
    );

    function successHandler(result) {
        console.log('Success: '+ result);
        alert(result);
    }

    function errorHandler(error) {
        console.log('Error: '+ error);
    }

     function onNotificationGCM(e) {
        alert("comming");
        if('registered' === e.event) {
            // Successfully registered device.
        }
        else if('error' === e.event) {
            // Failed to register device.
        }
    };
```

I am getting the respose as "OK".and i am not able call                                                'ecb': onNotificationGCM' // callback function

In Android console I am getting the bellow Message

```
V/PushPlugin(2512): execute: action=register 
V/PushPlugin(2512): execute: data=     [{"senderID":"889953963751","ecb":"onNotificationGCM"}] V/PushPlugin(2512): execute: jo={"senderID":"889953963751","ecb":"onNotificationGCM"} V/PushPlugin(2512): execute: ECB=onNotificationGCM senderID=889953963751
    09-12 03:13:33.453: D/GCMRegistrar(2512): resetting backoff for com.ensis.hello
    09-12 03:13:33.613: V/GCMRegistrar(2512): Registering app com.ensis.hello of senders 889953963751
    09-12  W/PluginManager(2512): THREAD WARNING: exec() call to PushPlugin.register blocked the main thread for 181ms. Plugin should use CordovaInterface.getThreadPool().
```

Comment: Did you register in GCM ?

Comment: yes i have registered

Comment: did you get GCM Registration ID?

Comment: no i did not get any GCM Registration Id,I am sending senderID

Answer (score 0):

This is the push notification flow:

1. your app request a registration to the remote Apple or Google server
2. if the registration is ok, the remove server returns a token, that identify this specific app on your device
3. you send this token to your server, saving it (e.g. on a db)
4. you send a push notification (from your server) calling Apple or Google services with the message and the tokens of the users you want to notify
5. these services *push* to your device/app a notification with the message

You must follow all these steps in order to have push notification working.

For android you need to catch the registration id (token) inside the `registered` event of the notification handler:

```
function onNotificationGCM(e) {
    alert("comming");
    if('registered' === e.event) {
        // Successfully registered device.
        console.log("regID = " + e.regid);
        // save/send this registration id on your server
    } else if('error' === e.event) {
        // Failed to register device.
    }
};
```

For iOS you need to catch it in the succesHandler of the `register` function.

For more information look at [this example in the plugin repository](https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin/blob/master/Example/www/index.html).

Comment: in successHandler function i am getting response as "OK"

Comment: How ca i get the registrationid

Comment: i am not getting inside alert("comming");